# How to create list inside a list using UITableView

Tags: ios, uitableview

I have a requirement. Where I have to get the list of students and then I have to show their subjects in which they are enrolled in.

**Example**

Now you can see below I have list of students i.e Student1, student2, and so on. and each student have different number of subjects
[image]

**What I have done So far:**

I have created a Custom cell that Contains a Label and Empty vertical stackview.

Then in method ***tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath)*** I am running the for loop that makes some UiLabel dynamically and adds them into the vertical stackview

**Problem:**  By doing this I am getting what I want. But when I scroll up and down the for loop repeats data in the cell again and again on each scroll up/down

Please help if there is anyother way of doing that.

Comment: You can see this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46192271/how-to-show-custom-nested-lists-in-ios

Comment: You need to ensure that you reset the cell's content when it is reused, but why not use a section per student with the student name in the header and the subjects in the rows?

Comment: Please check my updated answer for customised section.

Answer (score 1):

You can use tableview with section.

1. Set student name in section
2. Set your subjects in cell

This is sample of tableview with section.
https://blog.apoorvmote.com/uitableview-with-multiple-sections-ios-swift/

#### Here is the sample code it is just for your reference.

```
class TableViewController: UITableViewController {

let section = ["pizza", "deep dish pizza", "calzone"]

let items = [["Margarita", "BBQ Chicken", "Pepperoni"], ["sausage", "meat lovers", "veggie lovers"], ["sausage", "chicken pesto", "prawns", "mushrooms"]]
// MARK: - Table view data source

override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, titleForHeaderInSection section: Int) -> String? {

return self.section\[section\]

}

override func numberOfSectionsInTableView(tableView: UITableView) -> Int {
 // #warning Incomplete implementation, return the number of sections

return self.section.count

}

override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
 // #warning Incomplete implementation, return the number of rows

return self.items\[section\].count

}

override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
 let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("tableCell", forIndexPath: indexPath)

// Configure the cell...

cell.textLabel?.text = self.items[indexPath.section][indexPath.row]

return cell

}
```

### Update

Customised section view
Create your custom view and show your view as section

```
override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, viewForHeaderInSection section: Int) -> UIView? {

    let view = UIView(frame: CGRect(x:0, y:0, width:tableView.frame.size.width, height:18))
    let label = UILabel(frame: CGRect(x:10, y:5, width:tableView.frame.size.width, height:18))
    label.font = UIFont.systemFont(ofSize: 14)
    label.text = "This is a test";
    view.addSubview(label);
    view.backgroundColor = UIColor.gray;
    return view

}
```

[Sample code for Customised section](https://samwize.com/2015/11/06/guide-to-customizing-uitableview-section-header-footer/)

### Update 2

Custom header with reference of cell

```
override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, viewForHeaderInSection section: Int) -> UIView? {
    let  headerCell = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("HeaderCell") as! CustomHeaderCell
    headerCell.backgroundColor = UIColor.cyanColor()

    switch (section) {
    case 0:
      headerCell.headerLabel.text = "Student Name 1";
      //return sectionHeaderView
    case 1:
      headerCell.headerLabel.text = "Student Name 2";
      //return sectionHeaderView
    case 2:
      headerCell.headerLabel.text = "Student Name 3";
      //return sectionHeaderView
    default:
      headerCell.headerLabel.text = "Other";
    }

    return headerCell
  }
```

Comment: Android teem, If this answer is working for you then please accept my answer. This is very helpful for me.

Comment: I will try this. But I dont like sections As I just want to show sections and custom cell to look like one and then a space between other section .

Comment: Also I want to put the edit button to right of section

Comment: Try to remove footer space then your space between other section problem will be solved.

Comment: can I create my custom view in storyboard

Comment: Just create cell and give reference of section header, Please check my updated answer

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/170774/discussion-between-vivek-and-android-teem).

Answer (score 0):

You can try a different approach. Make a list with number of sections = number of students. Each section should have number of rows equal to the subjects for that student. This can be achieved easily by making a student model with subjects array as it's property.

```
class Student: NSObject {
    var subjectsArray : [String] = []
}
```

Answer (score 0):

First add this extension to your source code.

```
extension UIStackView{
    func removeAllArrangedSubviews() {
        let removedSubviews = arrangedSubviews.reduce([]) { (allSubviews, subview) -> [UIView] in
            removeArrangedSubview(subview)
            return allSubviews + [subview]
        }
        removedSubviews.forEach({ $0.removeFromSuperview() })
    }
}
```

Now override this method in your Custom cell class. it will remove all child views from stackview before reuse.

```
override func prepareForReuse() {
    super.prepareForReuse()
    self.stackView.removeAllArrangedSubviews()
}
```